# Twitter login does not work using firebase UI Auth "app-not-installed"

Tags: firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to implement twitter login through firebase UI. I've added generated secret keys and callback just like facebook login example. But it still does not work I get this error:
The requested mobile application corresponding to the identifier (Android package name or iOS bundle ID) provided is not installed on this device.
[image]

I tried adding different callback as I found it helped others. But no luck for me:
[image]

Comment: Have you enabled it on firebase?

Comment: @Jandroid yes I did

Comment: Try re-registering your app on firebase.

Comment: Also, did you add the API key and API secret to strings.xml?

Comment: @Jandroid yes, did both

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and the solution is to add `SHA-1` code to the Firebase Project Settings. So generate SHA-1 code and add the code to the `Project Settings` in your Firebase Console.

Comment: I already have SHA-1 added in firebase. Otherwise Facebook, Gmail and other logins would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed Twitter App on mobile device?

Comment: Hey @ShanakaAnuradha, I don't have twitter on my phone but it worked!

Comment: Twitter app should not be necessary